# Does Spree shop support multiple vendors to buy from?

Tags: spree

Hi i need a shop software where i can offer products from different vendors. e.g. one could buy a watch from 3 different vendors for different prices. Amazon does this too. (see http://www.amazon.de/gp/offer-listing/B0031SZRZG/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new)

Are there any plugins for that in Spree?

Answer (score 8):

Yep spree has plugin for spree multi vendor ,spree multi store as well spree multi tenant

spree multistore
https://github.com/bullrico/spree-multistore

spree multi tenant
https://github.com/stefansenk/spree_multi_tenant

spree multi vendor
https://github.com/chamnap/spree-multi-vendor

or you can use a specific Id for each store and add it to products and admin and add custom feature for multi store

Comment: thanks for the answer, but: spree-multistore is very outdated, multi_tenant is not like amazon, its one completely seperate spree shop per vendor. multi-vendor seems to do this too. We programmed the multistore feature ourselfes now btw

Comment: oh that's cool so may be providing or showing what you did or answering your own question will be a good idea

Comment: @Gaul How difficult was it to create your own solution? Please consider viewing my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828747/is-spree-extensible-enough-to-support-multiple-vendors-in-one-app-just-like-amaz. Thanks