# eCommerce solution for ruby on rails with multi-store support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, spree

As i know in rails there is limited support for eCommerce solution(few options):

1. Spree
2. Ror-e
3. Substruct
4. Piggybak

I didn't use any of this, but wanted to ask that anyone have experience between these solutions, pros&cons. I found similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382268/clean-e-commerce-app-with-user-friendly-non-techie-proof-admin-interface
but is relatively outdated. So my main question here does any of these solutions has support for **multi-store(multi-domain) concept**? So i need something like:

1. shop1.myWebApp.com
2. shop2.myWebApp.com
3. shop3.myWebApp.com

From here: [Does Spree shop support multiple vendors to buy from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871530/does-spree-shop-support-multiple-vendors-to-buy-from), i see Spree does that but from answers from that question i can assume that spree-multistore is very outdated.

**Edit:**
As i can see the most recent version of extension is 1.3?

So wanted to ask is everything ok then with my GemFile(is this proper way to install everything):

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-0-stable'

gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '2-0-stable'

gem 'spree_multi_domain', git: 'git://github.com/spree/spree-multi-domain.git',
branch: '2-0-stable'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not natively supported by Spree, however, it is supported by a few Spree extensions.  We use https://github.com/spree/spree-multi-domain for our sites to achieve this.

Comment: These extension is not-compatible with rails 4.0.0 ?

As i can see the latest stable version of these multi-domain extension is 1.1.x, so with these i can use spree version 1.1.0 or 1.1.4? If i go with spree version 1.1.4 i'm limited to rails version 3.2.9 or below?

Comment: The most recent version of that extension is compatible with Spree 2.0.  Spree 2.1 uses Rails 4.0, and the extension would need to be upgraded if you wanted to use it with Spree 2.1 and Rails 4.0.

Comment: Can you see edit of question about installation please.

Comment: That looks like a reasonable Gemfile.

Comment: is there any demo/live sites that uses this spree-multi-domain extension ?