# Is Spree extensible enough to support multiple vendors in one app just like Amazon.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce, spree

In short, is it possible to build an Amazon clone without substantial modification to Spree?

Comment: Yes, it is possible (check spree_multi_tenant - we're building one site on top of it) but it depends what you treat as `substantial modification` since Spree is very flexible so it can be quite easy and very hard, depends on your business logic/specification.

Comment: @zrl3dx Thanks! did you find `spree_multi_tenant` very helpful? What issues have you encountered?

Comment: it is indeed possible. If you do, don't use spree as an engine, just use the whole sourcecode as itself. If you use it as an engine, you'll end up overriding so much features of spree that you will be lost totally! Also use and extend the tests, that come with spree. You will however loose the ability to update spree, because you will have to change a lot of stuff in the core.

Comment: That's way too broad question to answer it here, we've got 20k LOC of our custom code built on top of Spree and none of our issues was caused by spree (or multitenant) itself, there were some issues with updating `order` from scope of single tenant but that can be resolved with un-tenanting `OrderUpdater` and so on. Also, cancan (yes, we should switch to cancancan ;)) abilities are moderately complicated now but that's nothing that cannot be resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Gaul! Post your comment as an answer!

Comment: Thanks @zrl3dx! Post your comment an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is indeed possible. If you do, don't use spree as an engine, just use the whole sourcecode as itself. If you use it as an engine, you'll end up overriding so much features of spree that you will be lost totally! Also use and extend the tests that come with spree. You will however loose the ability to update spree, because you will have to change a lot of stuff in the core.